# Function parameters in PHP

Tags: php, function, parameters

Hello Stack overflow community, you awesome lot you...I need your expertise...

Can I use the return variable from one function to act as an argument in the parameter of another, i.e.

```
  function getdata($filename) {
     //code
    return $result;
    }

    function totaldatafiles($result) {
      //code
        return $result2;
       }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes. But like this:

```
<?php
...
$filename = 'your-file-name';
$final_result = totaldatafiles(getdata($filename));
```

Comment: Well, you could do that in a class, where you would hide such thing as a function call inside another, so you wouldn't have to call it explicitly like that. I don't think things like that are bad practice though. It all depends on the complexity of your code, imho.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following three functions :

```
function getdata($filename) {
    //code
    return $result;
}

function totaldatafiles($data) {
    //code
    return $result;
}

function printoutput($string) {
    echo $string;
}
```

Now, you could do this :

```
$filename = 'myfile.txt';
$data = getdata($filename);
$total = totaldatafiles($data);
printoutput($total);
```

However, you could also do this :

```
printoutput(totaldatafiles(getdata('myfile.txt')));
```

Both do the exact same thing.

I can't think of any downsides to the second option, except that it's less readable.